# selecting columns in the same order as names from an array containing column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of say, 5 columns. I also have an array which contains some of these column names. I want a new data frame, consisting of only the columns whose names are present in this array, but in the same order as they appear in the array. I am able to get the columns, but not in the same order. Please see code below

```
col1 = c(1,1,1,1,1)
col2 = c(2,2,2,2,2)
col3 = c(3,3,3,3,3)
col4 = c(4,4,4,4,4)
col5 = c(5,5,5,5,5)
df = data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
df
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    1    2    3    4    5
2    1    2    3    4    5
3    1    2    3    4    5
4    1    2    3    4    5
5    1    2    3    4    5

columnsarray = c("col4","col1","col2")
df[which(names(df) %in% columnsarray)]
  col1 col2 col4
1    1    2    4
2    1    2    4
3    1    2    4
4    1    2    4
5    1    2    4
```

As you can see, I have mentioned the columns names as col4, col1, col2. However, the output looks like col1 col2 col4.

Comment: Just `df[columnsarray]` will do

Comment: @bergant, wow that's fantastic. Can you please add this as an answer, so I can accept

Answer (score 1):

if you want it in the order of you vector try this :

```
df[columnsarray[columnsarray %in% names(df)]]
# col4 col1 col2
# 1    4    1    2
# 2    4    1    2
# 3    4    1    2
# 4    4    1    2
# 5    4    1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `df[columnsarray]` will do.

You can use `df[,columnsarray]` also, but in case of `length(columnsarray) == 1` you will get a vector (not data.frame).

```
> str( df[c("col4")] )
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ col4: num  4 4 4 4 4

> str( df[,c("col4")] )
 num [1:5] 4 4 4 4 4
```